# Concatenate numbers as strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with data as below:

```
A  B  C
1  0  
1  1  1
1  1  0
```

I want to write a python code which would concatenate the values in A, B & C in column D as shown below:

```
A  B  C  D
1  0     10
1  1  1  111
1  1  0  110
```

In excel this can be done by =A1&B1&C1&D1

I want to replicate the same with pandas.

Comment: What have you tried and where do you run into problems?

Comment: Empy first value in `C` column is `NaN` ? Or empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with replace missing values and converting to strings if necessary:

```
df['D'] = [''.join(x) for x in df.fillna('').astype(str).to_numpy()]
print (df)
   A  B    C    D
0  1  0  NaN   10
1  1  1    1  111
2  1  1    0  110
```

If performance is not important:

```
df['D'] = df.fillna('').astype(str).agg(''.join, axis=1)
df['D'] = df.fillna('').astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but, pandas is reading it as float, so i added astype int
df['D'] = [''.join(x) for x in df.fillna('').astype(int, errors = 'ignore').astype(str).to_numpy()].
the output is coming out as 1.01.01.0

Comment: @MDJ - You can use `df['D'] = [''.join(x) for x in df.fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str).mask(df.isna(),'').to_numpy()]`